# How to get email address in the "to" field from ActionMailer view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, actionmailer, helper

I want to make a method accessible from a mailer view that returns a boolean depending on the user that the email is being sent to.

For example, let's say the user has an attribute `is_subscriber` which can be true or false. 
The method would contain something like this:

```
def show_banner?
  FeatureManager.is_feature_available?(:subscription_banners) && !user.is_subscriber
end
```

I want to access this method from within the mailer views.

The problem is, I have a lot of mailers in my app (UserMailer, SubscriptionMailer, FollowUpMailer) and relying on an instance variable @user for each mailer seems a bit dangerous.

**Is there any way I can access the email address from the "to" field as in this example** so I can find the user by his email address:

```
mail :to => @user.email, :subject => I18n.t('welcome_mail.subject')
```

**Is it a good idea to do that or is there a more generic way of making such helper method?**

Answer (score 13):

You can use *@_message* in actionview which gives you access to the message object from which you can access fields like 'to', 'from'.

I had a case where I need a unsubscribe button on all mails, So placed it in my layout which was used across mailers. I used the above solution to find the mail receiver and implement unsubscribe for the respective mail.

Comment: What if your "to" field has multiple recipients and you don't want to use bcc?  Seems like @_message just returns the mail object, but retrieving the actual recipient in this case isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `message.to`.

```rb
message.to #=> steve@apple.com
```

You also have access to `from` and `subject`, which can be very handy when setting the title of a Mailer View to the same thing as the `subject`. That's what we do with this.

Here's the link to the [Official Rails Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#using-action-mailer-helpers).

*I only found out about this when we were on **Rails 7**, so it may work for older version as well. If anybody can confirm that, please comment or edit this post.*